AWS Terraform: set provisioned concurrency integration request
I want to use the latest published lambda version for API Gateway integration request.
Terraform publishes and creates the version correctly.**
aws_lambda_provisioned_concurrency_config.getMonthlyCapacityConcurrency: Creation complete after 1m55s [id=ul-get-capacity-month-service-sandbox-function-us-east-1:11]**
But the published version is not set if I use the qualified_arn**
main.tf**
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "api_proxy_capacitymonth_integration" {
  rest_api_id              = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.usage_api.id
  resource_id              = aws_api_gateway_resource.usage_month_api_resource.id
  http_method              = aws_api_gateway_method.usage_capacitymonth_proxy.http_method
  type                     = var.aws_integration_proxy_type
  integration_http_method  = var.post_http_method
  uri                      = module.get_capacity_month_lambda.qualified_arn
  passthrough_behavior     = var.passthrough_behavior
}

Output.tf
output "qualified_arn" {
  value = aws_lambda_function.lambda_function.qualified_arn
}

I'm getting below error while executing the terraform script

Error: updating API Gateway Integration (agi-e7k0z02xc3-yffwns-GET): BadRequestException: AWS ARN for integration must contain path or action

I'm trying to set the qualified_arn for API Gateway Integration request. But terraform script is returning error.
